# Garbage collect commits in git

Tags: git

I have some commits created by `git subtree` that I want to have garbage collect (more that any practical purpose just to understand what and why can get collected).

I have already checked that these commits are not referenced the following ways:

```
# In any reflog
> git reflog --all --no-abbrev-commit | grep <hash>
(no output)

# In any branch, local or remote
> git branch --contains <hash>
(no output)
> git branch -r --contains <hash>
(no output)

# In any tag
> git tag --contains <hash>
(no output)

# In the current index
> git rev-list HEAD | grep <hash>
(no output)

# In references from filter-branch
> ls .git/refs/original/
(the folder does not exist)
```

These are the place that [git gc documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) lists that could contain references.

Still the given commits still exist after `git gc`.

Am I missing something? Or is there any git plumbing command that checks all this references?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Every time I want to delete loose objects, I use the following commands:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/*
git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0
git repack -A -d
git prune
```

Comment: Excellent, what was missing was the repacking. Even unreachable objects will not be disposed if packed with reachable objects. So the `repack` separates them and then `git prune` or `git gc` will properly dispose them.

Comment: Even when using `git prune`, my repository still had loose objects. If you experience this, `git gc` doc indicates that it tries *very hard* to be safe and keeps any possible references. Make sure to clean your /refs, /logs, FETCH_HEAD and other cache you might find in your .git folder. Then re-run `git gc --prune=now` will do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Commits (or objects in general) aren't actually deleted until they've been unpacked into loose objects and left that way for at least 2 weeks. You can use `git gc --prune=now` to skip the 2 week delay.

Normally what happens is git will pack your objects together into a packfile. This provides much better compression and efficiency than having loose objects. This typically happens whenever a `git gc` is executed. However, if an object is unreferenced, then `git gc` will unpack it back into a loose object.

Once unpacked, `git gc` will automatically prune old loose unreferenced objects. This is controlled by the `--prune=<date>` flag, which defaults to 2 weeks ago, so it prunes any old unreferenced object older than 2 weeks. By specifying `--prune=now`, you're asking `git gc` to prune any objects that are older than right now, which basically means to prune any unreferenced objects that exist.

Comment: Tried this and still the commit is not collected.

Comment: @LopSae: Have you tried running `git fsck --unreachable` to make sure that your commits are truly unreachable?

Comment: Just tried and it is not displayed, meaning that is reachable from somewhere, but I cant find from where.

Comment: @LopSae: Did you check if you have any other refs in `refs/*` besides branches and tags?

Comment: @LopSae: You could try `git describe --all --contains <hash>`

Comment: Yep, also checked that there are not any missing refs. `git describe --all --contains <hash>` actually fails displaying `fatal: cannot describe '<hash>'`

Comment: @LopSae did you replace `<hash>` with your commit hash?

Comment: Haha, yes, I did, I replaced back 'hash' in the response just to not clutter the comments.

Comment: What was missing here is that `git gc` will not unpack unreachable objects.