# Remove a branch including its commits

Tags: git, gitk

I have created a branch where I was trying an approach to a problem which didn't work out, so I want to delete the branch, including all commits I made on it. For the sake of the argument, my branches look like this (when viewed with Gitk):

```
A--B--C--D Master
    \
     \-E-F Unwanted
```

I want it to look like this:

```
A--B--C--D Master
```

If I delete the Unwanted branch I end up with this instead:

```
A--B--C--D Master
    \
     \-E-F
```

I have no use for commits E and F, and don't want them cluttering my Git history.

Apologies for what may seem to be a very simple (and possibly stupid) question, but I've been unable to find a suitable answer elsewhere.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991916/garbage-collect-commits-in-git for how to force commits to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's all you do. As long as E and F aren't referenced in any branch or tag, they'll eventually be garbage collected. I assume you're looking at it in gitk and still see the commits hanging out. If you restart gitk or do a forced reload with Ctrl+F5, they'll disappear. They're still there, but git will take care of them eventually. While you can force them to be cleaned up immediately, that's not a good habit to get into. The default time-to-live of 2 weeks for orphaned commits is there because just *sometimes* you really *did* want those commits, and you just didn't know it yet, so leave them orphaned and move on.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `git gc` it will remove unreferenced branches (which `F` is, assuming you didn't tag it or derive other branches from it) when they are older than a certain threshold (2 weeks default, and you can adjust it with `--prune=<date>`).