# How to remove previously added git subtree and its history

Tags: git, git-subtree

Many moons ago I added a subtree to my `git` repository. This subtree included several folders and files. I added the subtree instead of creating a submodule (as recommended). Now I realize I only want one of the files in the subtree and none of the rest. Even worse, when others `clone` my repository, what they get is not what is expected—there is some conflict with the subtree and the other code that I've created.

I can get ride of the files/folders with

```
git rm subtree–folder1 subtree_folder2 subtree_files.*
```

however, I'm still left with a lengthy commit history from the subtree.

I've done a fair amount of development since I originally added the subtree and can't lose the commit history that I've generated.

In short this is what I would like:

1. Remove all the subtree files/folders.
2. Forget the history of all the subtree commits.
3. Left with only my code and my history.

Is this possible?

PS. One possible complication is that I moved the single header file I wanted to keep from the subtree to some folder in my code. I hope this is not what is keeping me from forgetting the subtree history.

## An Attempt

After a fresh checkout from the remote server I have the following:

```
$ ls
.git             CMakeLists.txt   Read.cpp         logging.conf
.gitignore       ENDF6            TestData         src
.sparse-checkout LICENCE          doc              test
.travis.yml      README.md        include          tools
```

Where `.gitignore` only has:
    build/
    debug/

When I try the command as suggested I don't get a very happy response:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -rf test tools src doc LICENCE README.md .travis.yml' HEAD
Rewrite 2fec85e41e40ae18efd1b130f55b14166a422c7f (1/1701)fatal: pathspec 'test' did not match any files
index filter failed: git rm --cached -rf test tools src doc LICENCE README.md .travis.yml
```

I'm not sure why it says it has a problem with `test` when it is clearly there. I'm baffled.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `git rm <subtree name>` to remove the subtree?

Comment: @hunch_hunch I did that as well as the commands here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890047/how-to-remove-history-of-deleted-git-subtree-folder but I still have all the history of the subtree. Help!

Comment: You are OK with rewriting your repository history via rebase or filter-branch?

Comment: @AndrewC I'm okay with rewriting my repository history as long as I keep the history of my changes.

Comment: Did you try either  a tree or index filter operation?  https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html

Comment: @AndrewC I've tried them, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: I'd need to see the filter branch you ran, and a description of how it didn't work.

Comment: You need to add " --ignore-unmatch" to the `git rm`.  You probably also want to add `--prune-empty` to the filter branch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62556/discussion-between-jeremy-and-andrew-c).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use a filter-branch along with the --prune-empty option to remove any commits that no longer introduce new changes.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -rf dir1 dir2 dirN file1 file2 fileN' --prune-empty -f HEAD
```

After that, if you want to recover disk space you will need to delete all the original refs that filter branch saved, expire the reflog, and garbage collect.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It isn't shown here, but in our chat @AndrewC provided the answer needed.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland See the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62556/discussion-between-jeremy-and-andrew-c) jlconlin is referring, although it should be here the solution. Mm

Comment: Is this the right answer: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -rf dir1 dir2 dirN file1 file2 fileN' --prune-empty -f HEAD`?  @AndrewC could you update the answer if it is incorrect, or comment?

Comment: @fuzzyTew if you look at the comment/chat history you can see it worked for the OP.  That said, filter-branch has been supplanted in recent times by the 'filter-repo' command so if you were starting now you might want to consider that.

Comment: I infer you must have updated the answer from the chat some time ago.  Great.  `filter-repo` now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git filter-branch` to apply an operation to all the commits you made in a branch. This includes deleting files from each commit as you rewrite the entire history. A good description and instructions is available here: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/06/ignoring-doesnt-remove-a-file.html. You may find the following question useful as well: [Completely remove files from Git repo and remote on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/completely-remove-files-from-git-repo-and-remote-on-github) (it is where I found the link). The actual command you will run with this solution is going to be something like `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -rf subtree–folder1 subtree_folder2' HEAD`.

Another way, which is probably overkill for what you are doing, is cherry-picking. Cherry-picking allows you to rewrite any portion of your history that you like with any level of detail you like: `http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick`. You will want to do something like `git reset --hard <HASH of commit that introduced the subtree>`, followed by a series of

```
git cherry-pick -n <following commit hashes>
git reset
git add -p
git commit
```

for each subsequent commit you had made. This will allow you to remove the subtree from each commit you made in the past. You can refer to [partly cherry-picking a commit with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526044/partly-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git) for more information on effective cherry-picking. When you are done with this version of the deletion, you will want to remove the old commits that are no longer part of your branch:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Other referenced questions:
[How to move a branch backwards in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923055/how-to-move-a-branch-backwards-in-git)
[Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling)