# Forgot to use `--squash` and now the commit history is a mess. How can I clean up this mess?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-log, git-subtree

I was supposed to perform `subtree pull --squash`  for a third-party module that my project depends on, but I accidentally forgot to put `--squash`. Now my project commit history is flooded with the third-party module commits. They are scattered all over the log.

This mess needs to be gone. How would I identify all the commits that belongs to the third-party module, squash them into one, and then purge them from my project history, if possible at all?

**More info:**

Note that I have done several commits, that I intend to keep, after the broken operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `git reflog` to find your project's state from before you did the broken operation.
2. Check out that hash or `git reset --hard` to it.
3. Redo the operation with the correct flags.

Comment: Thanks Carl. My situation, however, is a bit more complicated. I have  done several commits, which need to be kept, after the broken operation. How can I undo the broken operation while selectively keeping some commits that happened after the broken operation?

Comment: Do you know which commits are yours?  Just cherry pick or rebase them after you fix things up.

Comment: For deleting the commits that are left over from the unsquashed operation try this: [Garbage Collect Commits in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991916/garbage-collect-commits-in-git)

Comment: @LopSae - Appreciate the tip. I was head-scratching on how to deal with that.

Comment: I completely know the feeling :)