# git subtree split - the tags are not transferred

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-tag

I have a git project that has one big root directory:

```
C:\MyProject\MyProject
C:\MyProject\.git
```

And then all the files and subdirectories are inside `C:\MyProject\MyProject`. I want to remove that redundant root directory, so I used this command:

```
git subtree split -P MyProject -b MyBranch
git checkout MyBranch
git branch -D master
git branch -m MyBranch master
```

There is a problem with this solution, however - **the tags are still attached to the now-deleted**, original master branch:

[image]

The gray branch is the original master branch, the red branch is the new one without the redundant directory, but the tags are still attached to the old branch's checkins.

Comment: Tags point to specific commits. Your subtree operations are creating a new set of commits (granted, some of the content is still the same, but they are new commits, regardless). If you need the tags moved, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: In my case it's not "some", there is a 1-1 correspondence for all commits, all I do is remove the redundant root directory. But yeah, unfortunately, it seems that's it. I just checked and the tags are 10 in total, so I'll 'migrate' them by hand.

Answer (score 2):

`git filter-branch` might be able to do the movement you want and migrate all branches and other references, like tags. The `--subdirectory-filter` will do an operation similar to the subtree that you are creating:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter subDirectory -- --all
```

[Check this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757601/git-splitting-repository-by-subfolder-and-retain-all-old-branches/20793890#20793890) for better detail on how to setup the repository for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter <ProjectSubFolder> 
--tag-name-filter cat -- --branches
```

That transfered the tags too but kept a dangling branch with tracking references so I removed by hand the file .git\refs\original\refs\heads\master and the dangling branch dissappeared.