# Split one subfolder from git repository with all branches and history

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I would like to split on folder from my git repository into new one. But I would like to keep all open/closed branches and history for everything related to this folder.

```
\ Source Repo
--\ AAA
--\ BBB
----\ DDD
----\ EEE
--\ CCC


\ New Repo 1
--\ AAA
--\ CCC

\ New Repo 2 (BBB subfolder)
--\ DDD
--\ EEE
```

I followed steps described here https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/ - but this work only for a single branch. At the end - I get new repository with all (?) commits but no branch information is present.

I tried to do this for all branches using `--all` parameter, but I'm not clear how to push all rewritten branches to the empty remote repo.

Here is what I have currently:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME
$ cd REPOSITORY-NAME
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME -- --all
```

At this point if I look at my local repo, I seem to have all history and all branches in remotes origins.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git (push)
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git (push)


$ git push -u origin --all
```

Last command doesn't seem to be pushing all branches. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move a single directory from a git repository to a new repository whilst maintaining the history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811251/how-can-i-move-a-single-directory-from-a-git-repository-to-a-new-repository-whil)

Comment: One you referring to is actually very brief. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475 and found most information there. But neither one of these are exact my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git splitting repository by subfolder and retain all old branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757601/git-splitting-repository-by-subfolder-and-retain-all-old-branches)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found missing pieces of information here [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475)

Finished scripts looks like this. Use this process for both new repositories with one line being different

Clone source repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME
$ cd REPOSITORY-NAME
```

Re-create all remote branches locally

```
$ for i in $(git branch -r | sed "s/.*origin\///"); do git branch -t $i origin/$i; done
```

Use filter-branch to trim everything for required subfolder (this will create new repo using only FOLDER-NAME

```
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME -- --all
```

Use filter-branch to remove FOLDER-NAME (this will create new repository with everything but FOLDER-NAME)

```
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -rf FOLDER-NAME' -- --all
```

Update remote URL to new empty repo:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git (push)
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git (push)
```

Push everything together

```
$ git push -u origin --all
```