# How to revert to previous commit and remove later commits in Git

Tags: git

Wanted to revert to previous commit by

```
$ git reset --hard commit_sha
```

Which seems to revert successfully with HEAD is now at that previous commit but within PyCharm log I still see the later commit in branch history.

So my question is how to remove that later commit ? i.e. image here, I want to remove commit `7e260f7`

Do I right click on `7e260f7` or the commit named TEMP CHANGE GROUP and select 'Reset Current Branch to Here'?

Because the `origin/master` `7e260f7` is still in BitBucket?

```
$ git reset --hard 7e260f7
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Garbage collect commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991916/garbage-collect-commits-in-git)

Comment: Have you tried restarting PyCharm or deleting its internal cache? It's possible it's just storing them internally.

Comment: Hi Dan, but the commit is still showing in Bitbucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your branch `master` on remote `origin` is still pointing to the commit you're trying to remove. You need to force update the remote branch using `git push origin master --force`.

There is also a difference between `reset` and `revert` which is worth knowing.

When you use `git reset` you move the branch pointer to the commit you specify. You essentially move backwards through the history. Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

When you use `git revert` you reverse the changes that the commit you specify made and create another commit containing those reversed changes. In this instance you will create an additional commit with the reversed change set. Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @anierzad, just did $ git push origin master --force. So what is the equivalent for that within PyCharm or WebStorm thanks

Comment: Glad to help :). I'm afraid I don't have any experience with those. You should just need to perform the equivalent of a fetch if those programs are still showing the commit.

Comment: Hi @anierzrad, now I am facing similar issue of git checkout previous commit and with changes I then committed and pushed a new change, but the HEAD is now ahead of the master origin/master, so do I do the similar command as above to sync? Because Bitbucket also does not see it?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're asking. Is it related to this question or something else that's occurred?

Comment: Similar, but now HEAD is ahead of origin/master

Comment: That could mean you've just made some additional commits and haven't pushed the changes to your remote yet.

Use `git log` to check the history is what you expect it to be. If it is, use `git push` to push to your remote.

That should sort you out.