# GIT Overwrite author of code lines (git blame)

Tags: git, url-rewriting, history, blame

I was trying to find the answer everywhere on the internet but was unsuccessful.

My problem is that, for some reason, on a new laptop, I put 'email' instead of 'name' and 'password' instead of 'email'. And now, in history, everyone can see my email and its password (facepalm).

So my question is: is there a way to rename the author's name and email in history?

p.s: commit is still in the local branch

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7PZf.png)

Comment: Surely this is a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73140498/184546).

Comment: @TTT Not really: here the changes were not pushed yet, so it's a much simpler situation to fix.

Comment: @joanis I would have thought the same as you since it sort of sounds like it wasn't pushed yet because "commit is still in the local branch". But I had already seen the other question from the day before so I knew... The other question seems to have been written by a co-worker. (What are the odds of this identical problem happening twice within 1 day of each other?) That being said, if the question didn't include the 2nd paragraph, I wouldn't have known it was a dup.

Comment: @TTT Good spotting, I should have recognized that since I even answered that duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

You literally can't *fix* the bad commit, but you can *stop using it* and then be careful not to send it out to any *other* Git repository so that no one else can see it.

To make a new-and-improved variant of the existing commit, you must copy the original (bad) one to the new-and-improved one.  Copying the *last* commit on a branch while changing the author information is easy:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

will use your current `user.name` and `user.email` settings.  The existing final commit will be "kicked off the end of the branch", as in this drawing:

```
...--G--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Here `H` is the "bad" commit and is the most recent; this is "before `git commit --amend`".  This becomes:

```
       H
      /
...--G--I   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Note how commit `H` is still present in your Git repository, but unless you can *find its hash ID*, you cannot *see* commit `H` any more.

If the "bad" commit is further back in the chain:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

where, say, commit `F` is bad, you have a more difficult task: you must kick commit `F` off the chain, but this also kicks commits `G` and `H` off the chain.  This means you must copy `F` to a new and improved `I`, and then copy `G` and `H` as well.  This is harder to do well since `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` want to preserve the original author information, but it's still possible, especially with `git rebase -i` and `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple commit amend fixed the issue. Sorry for the useless post.

```
git commit --amend --author="Fedor <fedor@bodr.com>"
```

Comment: Don't forget to clean up a bit for the dangling commit. Take a look at answers in @TTT's duplicate suggestion above.